Set Collider2D friction at runtime without modifying Physics2D material
I have a set of objects that all share the same physics configurations and therefore a single Physics2D material.  Multiple of these objects can be active on a scene at the same time.
I would like to change the friction of these objects at runtime in a way that's independent of each other.  When I use Collider2D.sharedMaterial property this seems to change the material itself and that material as I mentioned is used in many other objects.  Is there a way I can update the friction of the objects at runtime in a way that's independent of each other?
If this can be accomplished while still using a Physics2D material great.  If not, I'm also OK on not using one, but in that case, I can't figure out how to set the friction of an object as the Collider2D.friction property seems to be read-only unlike the Collider2D.sharedMaterial.friction property.

Make and assign a copy of the material using Instantiate? .. hmm just checked again .. what can be done in 3D collider seems to be not supported for Collider2D ...

I ended up using your idea a bit differently, just creating a PhysicsMaterial2D physicsMaterial = new PhysicsMaterial2D() and copying the properties of the rigidbody2D.sharedMaterial then assigning it to the colliders of interest.  Then changing the friction of this at runtime works.  This seems extremely hacky though, is this really the best way to do something this simple?

Just fyi, for materials, if you mess with the properties without .sharedMaterial, e.g. Material.color, they will instead create a separate instance of the material on runtime, which you don't want in general and there's MaterialPropertyBlock to allow you per-instance values while retaining the same material asset. Unfortunately physics materials don't have that.

@NPatch in general the issue here is that Collider2D only has a sharedMaterial property but doesn't allow to access only an instance like material which was OPs intend here

@derHugo off topic I know, but I saw the parallel to Materials and they will resort to instantiating multiple PhysicsMaterials which usually is the wrong way to deal with regular materials. So I thought to clear that up.

If there aren't any better solutions @derHugo feel free to make an answer and I will accept it since my solution is practically a different flavor inspired by yours.

Other than for Collider (3D) there unfortunately is no material property for Collider2D that automatically would instantiate a copy of the material like you expect.
You could though do this "manually" using e.g.
var material = someCollider2D.sharedMaterial;
var copyMaterial = Instantiate(material);
// Make some modifications 
someCollider2D.sharedMaterial = copyMaterial;


And/Or alternatively if you already know beforehand you will need a fixed set of different settings you could of course also already beforehand simply create all the required physics material assets and reference them all in fields via the Inspector
[SerializeField] PhysicsMaterial2D defaultMaterial;
[SerializeField] PhysicsMaterial2D slippyMaterial;

and later assign them how and where required
someCollider2D.sharedMaterial = slippyMaterial;

